# Can a Scala for-yield return None if I pass in an Option to it?

Tags: scala

I have the following for-yield loop which takes in a boolean and should either yield Some(string) or None, depending on the boolean:

```
val theBoolean = false

val x: Option[String] =
for {
  theArg <- theBoolean
} yield {
  if (theArg) {
    "abc"
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

This works great if `theBoolean` is actually a Boolean like `false`. However if I wanted to pass in an `Option[Boolean]`:

```
val theBoolean = Some(false)
```

it seems like Scala automatically applies a Some() wrapper to the None return - I get a complaint that "Expression of type Option[Serializable] doesn't conform to expected type Option[String]" (with None being the Serializable). The yield is perfectly happy with the same string return though (it doesn't become an Option[Option[String]]

How would I return a None in this case?

Comment: I discovered that None.get actually makes the compiler happy. But it seems weird to use it this way.

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve?

Comment: An option gets passed in - under certain conditions I want to extract a string out of it, but under other conditions I want it to be None.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A for-comprehension is just syntactic sugar for a series of `flatMap`, `map` and `filter`.
Let's desugar your code then:

```
val theBoolean = Some(false)

val x = theBoolean.map { theArg =>
  if (theArg) {
    "abc"
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```

As you can see, you're just mapping over the value of the `Option`, so you'll either return `Some(abc)`, `Some(None)` or `None` (in case `theBoolean` is already `None`).

The lowest common type of `None` and `"abc"` is `java.Serializable`, so that's why the type of `x` is inferred as `Option[Serializable]`, which as meaningless as `Option[Any]`.

Possible solutions are:

- using a `flatMap`

  ```
  theBoolean.flatMap(theArg => if (theArg) Some("abc") else None)
  ```

  or even shorter

  ```
  theBoolean.flatMap(if (_) Some("abc") else None)
  ```
- filtering and mapping

  ```
  theBoolean.withFilter(identity).map(_ => "abc")
  ```

Where I used `identity` since you're testing the value itself.

Clearly you can always leverage the syntactic sugar provided by a for-comprehension, although it doesn't really make a difference in this case

```
for {
  theArg <- theBoolean
  if theArg
} yield "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, everything within the `yield` block is wrapped into an Option (that's how for-comprehensions for options work). In general, for-comprehensions describe what should be done with the content that can be found inside the monad on which for-comprehension is invoked, but the end result (for the world outside of the `yield` block) is still a monad of the same type (e.g. Option, Try or List).

On yet more general note: there are a lot of descriptions about what a monad is. You can assume that a monad is that infamous Schrödinger box and you are pondering what could happen with that cat hidden there, but all this still remains a possibility because the box isn't open yet.

A possible way to do what you want:

```
val theBoolean = false

val x: Option[String] =
for {
  theArg <- theBoolean if theArg
} yield {
  "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a for comprehension it sounds like you want a flatMap instead of a for comprehension.

```
scala> Some(false).flatMap(if (_) Some("abc") else None)   
res4: Option[String] = None
```